# Applying JavaScript after a cURL request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, curl

I am having some trouble applying JavaScript after I have used cURL to retrieve HTML data from an external website.

The idea is that it curl request makes a post to a website which returns a table of different results. For some reason I want to perform some javascript (preferably jQuery) on the results but it does not seem to work.

I believe it might be something to do with the order in which everything is loaded.

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jqc-1.11.3,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="table-responsive">
<?php

$search_term = $_POST["search_term"];

$regex = "/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i";

if (preg_match($regex, $search_term)) {

    $post_data['number'] = $search_term;
    $curl_connection = curl_init('http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/numbersearch.php');

} else {
    $post_data['search_name'] = $search_term;
    $curl_connection = curl_init('http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/companysearch.php');
}

foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($result);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$domTables = $xpath->query('.//div[@class="boardcontainer"]');
$tbclass = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
$tdtag = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');

//from the main database table only.
$table = $domTables->item(0);

//main loop throuth the table we pull from its source
foreach($table->childNodes as $child){ 


    //looks at the table tag and removes css from source
    foreach($tbclass as $tbclasses){
        $tbclasses->removeAttribute('cellpadding'); 
        $tbclasses->removeAttribute('cellspacing'); 
        $tbclasses->removeAttribute('border'); 
        $tbclasses->removeAttribute('width');

        //adds bootstrap css class for table 
        $tbclasses->setAttribute('class', 'table table-bordered');      
        $tbclasses->setAttribute('id', 'example');
    }

    //looks at the td tag within table and removes css from source
    foreach ($tdtag as $tdtags) {
        $tdtags->removeAttribute('class');      
        $tdtags->removeAttribute('width');
        $tdtags->removeAttribute('align');
        $tdtags->removeAttribute('bgcolor');
        $tdtags->removeAttribute('colspan');     
        $tdtags->removeAttribute('height');     
    }
    //outputs the html for display
    echo $child->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);   
}

/*
This used to work until I added the Dom Document part to it.
*/

if (empty($table)) {
        echo "Nothing found";
    }

//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);
?>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#example").DataTable();
    } );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried moving the JavaScript above the end **body** tag and also in the the head making sure jQuery loads first but no joy, even separated the header and footer into separate files but still no joy.

The only luck I have been having is using DOM Document to remove classes from the HTML that has been copied over during the cURL request, but I am unable to apply any.

I added

```php
$tbclasses->setAttribute('id', 'example');
```

To hope use the getElementByID() however I get the impression that it cant see it because it not part of the original HTML that was retrieved.

Any clues?
Many Thanks.

Comment: where's the javascript code? what does html look like and what exactly do you need to change in that html? This whole question isn't very clear. Note that whatever you do in the php you need to output first before javascript can do anything with it in browser

Comment: did you try to generate the complete html document WITH your JS code and returning it to the browser?

Comment: @charlietfl I have added some example JS, also I believe have outputted it. Is this "echo $child->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);" not enough?

Comment: @messerbill sounds like your suggesting I continue using Dom Document to add the JS that way instead of doing it afterwards?

Comment: cURL is running at server,javascript is running at frontend.All javascript run after cURL

Comment: Can you show me where is it not, as the way I understand it, it is running after the cURL @gumingfeng

Comment: No... javascript and php run in completely different environments and at different times. See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Comment: If curl_exec is an async function(probably),your code will go wrong.I have never used PHP,so i don't know your code is right or not.But for this requirement,there always two ways.One,fetch data at server(async),process the result,render response with result.Two,fetch data at frontend,do what u want with javascript

Answer (score 0):

you are not very clear about what want do with js, but maybe you just need execute js  when document ended be loaded. Ty put js code inside document ready:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   //your code
});
```

Comment: For now I am simply trying to apply DataTables from (https://datatables.net/)

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#example").DataTable();
    } );
</script>

Comment: My thinking is, it doesnt matter what JavaScript code I am trying to apply, its a matter of why cant any javascript code work at all during this process.

Comment: You have sure the html returned by curl is correct? Datatables its a little weird with html sintax. Note the php generate the html code, and only after js code run. So its almost sure that html has some problem.

Comment: I agree with you on both points, as the I noticed in DataTables they require "thead" and "th" to be in the tables html, something I am going to have to figure out how to inject using DomDocument again.

However it does not solve the issue that PHP seems to be rendering the HTML as I have outputted it, though my only evidence is the browser it self, view source shows the code as it should be, except the changes the JavaScript should be making. Weird.

Comment: cont: 
What do you reckon I am missing here using cURL and $DOM to produce HTML from a source that I must admit is very messy, but I believe I have cleaned it up very well using DomDocument and DOMXPath.

I think I might have to create a dummy site with with a similar layout but cleaner html and see if it works to determine if its a PHP out HTML issue.

Comment: Maybe you already know, but datatables allow create a table programmatically, i mean, you can sent header and data as params: $("#example").DataTable({column: /*header structure*/, data: /*row data*/});, in this way you just need define tag table with correct id.

Comment: Problem is the original table has no ID, hence why I had to add it using DOMDocument, something else that has be thinking why its not working, tanx for the tip will give it a go and see.